# Phonegap pause event not behaving correctly

Tags: jquery, cordova

I have a phonegap app built using jQuery Mobile.

I have bound event listeners to `pause` and `resume` like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false); 
}
```

Now, I have put `alerts` in the `onPause` and `onResume` functions. Those alerts do fire, <s>however any functions I try to call from those do not work. One of my functions `initialize` (basically restarts the app) works when called from anywhere in my code, however it does not fire when called from `onPause`. The other function I have tried is `clearInterval` and that does not work.</s>

On top of that, it doesn't appear that the `pause` event fires until the app is actually resumed, as in the alert doesn't trigger until the app is reopened.

I am trying to force the app to shutdown/logout when it is paused/sent to the background and that is not working.

Do I have any obvious faults, or am I missing something?

**Update**
My problem with the functions not firing was due to variable scope (stupid mistake) However, the pause event still fires *after* the app has been resumed.

Comment: What platform(s) are you targeting?

Comment: @KerriShotts Android 2.3+, or around there, and iOS 6+ or so.

Comment: Is the behavior the same on all platforms?

Comment: @KerriShotts I can't be sure about iOS but it seems to be the case for all androids.

Comment: @sharf did you managed to resolve this issue? If so, how? Thank you

Comment: @ApheX, I did, but I can't remember for sure if I fixed it, or came up with a workaround. I think my problem stemmed from the fact that I was not including a script tag pointing to `cordova.js`. Doing this fixed a lot of my problems.

Answer (score 5):

I think I had your exact same problem.  I had set the Phonegap config.xml variable KeepRunning to false.  I set to true and now it gets the pause event when it is supposed to. Here is the config.xml line I am talking about:

```
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
```

I suppose it makes sense that if the app is not running then the pause event code won't get run until the app runs again.  I guess KeepRunning has higher priority than listening to pause event.  It would be interesting to get a proper explanation as to why this is exactly at a lower level.

Comment: I just had the exact same issue. It would indeed be interesting why the onPause-Event isn't executed, yet other JavaScript code still runs --> even tough KeepRunning is set to "false". I'm gonna try updating my phonegap/cordova.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had also same issue. and when i set true. it was solved. like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can remember from some time ago, that I needed to wrap my `onResume` function with setTimeout and time value zero to be called accordingly, although I never figured out why. Maybe that's also the case for `onPause`.

Give it a try like that:

```
function onPause() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert("onPause");
    }, 0);
};
```

Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input but it didn't fix my issue. I can get the event to fire, it just fires after the app has been resumed, which is not how pause should work.

Comment: If you are talking about iOS, then perhaps the following from the [Phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause) could be of interest for you: "In the pause handler, any calls to the Cordova API or to native plugins that go through Objective-C do not work, along with any interactive calls, such as alerts or console.log(). They are only processed when the app resumes, on the next run loop." That could explain why the alerts are only firing on app resume.

Comment: This problem is on Android 2.3+ I've not tried it on iOS though, but that doesn't give me hope...

Comment: I have two pages. One is working fine. The other even console.log() in onPause is not firing. That's weird.

Comment: After applying this solution, it does work for me! (iOS)